# Problema ao hospedar Bot no Azure

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure, bot-framework

eu criei um bot muito simples usando o botframework e estou tentando hospedá-lo no Azure, quando executo localmente ele funciona com sucesso mas na nuvem está aparecendo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou colocando as chaves no web config:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse erro não diz nada sobre sua causa. Você tem algum log no servidor?

Comment: Está hospedado no Azure, lá eu só encontrei log de atividades, você se tem como verificar log de erros lá?

Comment: Claramente está dando erro no código do seu Bot. Se tiver usando AppService, tem como habilitar o Remote Debug para depurar. Sem mais detalhes - como qual a requisição e parte do codigo, não tem como ajudarmos mais.